# Why the element in same dtype's df show different type?

Tags: python, dataframe, dtype

There are two dataframes which contain same dtypes:

```
>>> df1.dtypes
code       object
date       object
open      float64
high      float64
low       float64
close     float64
volume      int64
dtype: object

>>> df2.dtypes
code       object
date       object
open      float64
high      float64
low       float64
close     float64
volume      int64
dtype: object
```

Why the element in their dataframe's columns show different type?

```
>>> x1 = df1['date'][0]
>>> x1
'19901219'
>>> x2 = df2['date'][0]
>>> x2
20050225
>>> type(x1)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(x2)
<class 'str'>
```

The concept `object` in pandas represents string.
[data-type description](https://datatofish.com/data-type-pandas-dataframe/)
I can infer that `x1`'s type should be `str` the same as `x2`,
Why `x1`'s type is `int` ,not the same as `x2`?

Comment: What do you mean why? `object` means *any python object*.

Comment: `object` means `str` !

Comment: https://datatofish.com/data-type-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'object' in pandas can be "str or mixed" in Python.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

> Pandas has two ways to store strings.
>
> 1. object dtype, which can hold any Python object, including strings.
> 2. StringDtype, which is dedicated to strings.